# Two different (isomorphic) splitting field

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

how I write in the title, studying the splitting field, I read there are a lot of extension of a field $\mathbb{K}$ in which $f(x)\in\mathbb{K}[x]$ can be write as a product of linear polynomials, minimal extension in the sense of inclusion. I know that this extensions are isomorphic, but I ask an example of two *different* extension.

Comment: Does something like $f(x) = x^2 - 2\in\Bbb Q[x]$ and the splitting fields $\Bbb Q[x]/(f(x))$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})\subseteq\Bbb R$ satisfy you?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean by "different".

Comment: Not equal, like the previuos example.